# C# Linq Query for compare two tables

Tags: c#, sql, linq, linq-to-sql

I want linq c# query to compare two tables and list unmatched record from table 1

Comment: Hello, please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask We will need allot more info to be able to help you

Answer (score 0):

```
List<MyClass> Unmatched = new List<MyClass>();

foreach (var row in Table_A)
{
if (Table_B.Count(x => x.ID == row.ID) == 0)
Unmatched.Add(row);
}
```

Something like that?

It will only check Unmached Table1 to Table2.
It doesn't check Table2 to Table1.

We need more details.

## EDIT

Comment: i have two tables one for lets take A table it has one column called 'id' and it has row values like 1,2,3,4,5. and B table has column 'id' and it has row values like 3,4,
and i want to display the output like only 1,2,5 in list .using linq query

Answer (score -1):

The last line of code compares the elements of two lists and with ! Contains keep only the unmatched elements of the first list and added to the new **Unmathced** list:

```
List<string> table_1 = new List<string>() { "panos", "mitsos", "alex", "niki" };

List<string> table_2 = new List<string>() { "panos", "mitsos", "alexandros", "maria" };

List<string> UnmatchedList= new List<string>();

UnmatchedList = table_1.Where(x => !table_2.Contains(x)).ToList();
```